# A connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with usual topology has a boundary with no interior points?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying for a while that if $A$ is a connected space implies that $int(\overline{A})= \varnothing$ but I'm stuck. Please kindly help me :')

Comment: You say you have been trying for a while. What have you tried? Where is this problem from?

Comment: what you have claimed in the body of your question (is not true and) is different from what you ask in the subject.

Comment: To make the questions match, do you mean that the interior of the boundary is empty? That would be $int(\partial A)=\emptyset$. The overbar means the closure of a set. But also, where in your efforts you are stuck or confused?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Thomas, Sorry!, I didn't know what happen when I wrote the body. I wanted to write that if $A$ is a connected space, implies that $int(\partial A) $. If something is hard to read, my English is not very good, so sorry again.

Comment: @Arthur, I've tried via contradiction, but the only thing I get is that if $\partial A$ has an interior point $x$, then $A\cap B(x,\varepsilon) $ and $A^c \cap B(x, \varepsilon) $ are dense in $B(x,\varepsilon) $ with the subspace topology, so $A\cap B(x,\varepsilon) $ and $A^c \cap B(x, \varepsilon) $ has no interior points.

Comment: Can you find _any_ subset of $\Bbb R^n$ where $\operatorname{int}(\partial A)$ is non-empty?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}^n$, which is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the subset of $\Bbb R^2$ consisting of a vertical line at each rational $x$-coordinate, as well as a single horizontal line.